# Complex number visualisation when imaginary part is null in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, complex-numbers

In MATLAB R2012:

```
>> rand(3) ; ans(1,1)=1+i

ans =
     1.0000 + 1.0000i   0.5060             0.9593          
     0.7513             0.6991             0.5472          
     0.2551             0.8909             0.1386
```

But in R2013:

```
>> rand(3) ; ans(1,1)=1+i

ans =
     1.0000 + 1.0000i   0.9134 + 0.0000i   0.2785 + 0.0000i
     0.9058 + 0.0000i   0.6324 + 0.0000i   0.5469 + 0.0000i
     0.1270 + 0.0000i   0.0975 + 0.0000i   0.9575 + 0.0000i
```

How can I fix it?

Regards.

Comment: Why do you need it to hide the imaginary part if it's 0?  If it's for output purposes you can write your own output function to display it in exactly the format you want, e.g., using fprintf (to the screen or a file).  Starting in R2013 the built-in display function was changed in MATLAB to show the imaginary parts even if they are 0 - for consistency with Workspace display and since for some applications it's desirable to see the imaginary part even it is zero.  I don't believe there is any option to hide the imaginary part, but you could always submit a suggestion to mathworks.

Answer (score 1):

Without having the option to try, I can only guess that you may want to play around with the format.

My best bet would be `format shortg`, it may hide the imaginary part or simply make it less distracting:

```
rand(3) ; ans(1,1)=1+i
format shortg
rand(3) ; ans(1,1)=1+i
```

Yes that is `shortg` instead of `short`. It tries not to show irrelevant zeros and decimals.

Comment: @NicolásTorresa I think that is the minimum amount of distraction you can get by only changing the format. I know its not the same as making the complex part dissapear, but without applying a complex solution this may be as good as it gets for the standard output. If you don't mind calling a function to display your variables, you can create one that only prints the relevant numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to write this would be as a new function that simply outputs in the format you please.
Example:

```
function [ out ] = new_display( in )
for i=1:size(in,1)
    for j=1:size(in,2)
        fprintf('%.4f', real(in(i,j)));
        if(imag(in(i,j)))>0
            fprintf(' + %.4fi\t', imag(in(i,j)));
        else
            fprintf('\t\t\t');
        end
    end
    fprintf('\n');
end
```

Gives:

```
>> new_display(ans)
0.8147 + 1.0000j    0.9134          0.2785          
0.9058          0.6324          0.5469          
0.1270          0.0975          0.9575
```

Normally, if you just type `ans`, matlab calls the display() function. You could overload this function with your own, but MathWorks says that it is a bad idea (I agree).

Ref:

- http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/display.html
- http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/displaying-objects-in-the-command-window.html#bt3ji0p

Comment: I think ```if(imag(in(i,j)))>0``` should be ```if(imag(in(i,j)))~=0``` (because of negative imaginary parts).